# Dojo DataGrid - preventing column resize

Tags: datagrid, dojo

Is there a way to set a fixed column size in Dojo DataGrid, and not allow it to be resized by the user? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cells defined within the grid's `structure` support a boolean `noresize` property.  Setting this to `true` will disable resizing on that particular cell.

You might want to do something about overriding the default CSS though - it appears to use a rather noticeable cursor when hovering over non-resizable cell boundaries.

You can also set a specific width of a column in the `structure` using the `width` property on a particular cell.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kfranqueiro/qNfC9/

Comment: may be this is too late to comment.. I used this property, but the column gets re-sized when sorting is applied. Any idea how to lock column width when sorting is applied?