# Avoid adjusting dojox.grid.datagrid header width

Tags: datagrid, grid, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

- Below is my declarative dojox.grid.datagrid. I want to avoid re-sizing the column's width. In the UI am able to do column re-sizing. how to avoid it

  ```
  <div class="claro" id="customer" name="dataGrid" onclick="setWidgetproperty(this.id,'xy','inner__customer')" ondblclick="editCustomGrid(this.id)" onmouseup="setDocStyle(this.id)" style="height: 200px; left: 178px; position: absolute; top: 176px; width: 950px;">
   <table class="claro" dojotype="dojox.grid.DataGrid" id="inner__customer" rowselector="10px" style="height: 180px; width: 400px;">
        <thead>
             <tr>
                  <th field="Column1" width="100px">
                       Column1
                  </th>
                  <th field="Column2" width="100px">
                       Column2
                  </th>
                  <th field="Column3" width="100px">
                       Column3
                  </th>
                  <th field="Column4" width="100px">
                       Column4
                  </th>
                  <th field="Column5" width="100px">
                       Column5
                  </th>
             </tr>
        </thead>
   </table>
   <input id="hidden__customer" name="dataGrid" style="display:none;" type="hidden">
  ```

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered already, check out this post:

[Dojo DataGrid - preventing column resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871475/dojo-datagrid-preventing-column-resize)

You will have to switch from declarative to a programatic creation of the grid for being able to make use of the noresize attribute for each column.

Comment: i don't know, that is why i suggest switching to programatic mode ! Try adding data-dojo-props="noresize: true" to your th elements before switching, maybe it works...

Comment: ok better i will switch to programmatic mode. after giving noresize: true, can i able to re-size column's width using dojo slider?

Comment: i think that the noresize attribute  only disables the UI elements which allow the resize-stuff, a programatic resize would still be possible, but you would have to redraw the grid.